# jQuery click events which are under on mouseover javascript event are acting strange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have checked the other similar questions but I could not relate them to my problem. What I have here is a loop that fetches comments from database and their id is stored inside their html tag id so that I can use .filter() on the elements to detect them. I called my jQuery events on the filtered elements.

The problem is when the like or dislike icon is clicked, it triggers more than one event or doesn't trrigger at all. The conditions are not working properly either. I used alert functions to check how many times the events are being called. Most of the time they pop up more than twice.

It's working fine in this fiddle where it's not under onmouseover event.
 https://jsfiddle.net/8pmu5jLd/19/

But I need to have it under some function to pass the current id value that helps in .filter(). I don't understand what is causing the problem here.
The following are my php, js, and css codes:

**comments.php**

```
$output .= '
  <div>
    <p class="comment" id='.$rw['id'].'>'.$rw["texts"].'</p>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up like" onmouseover="func('.$rw['id'].',event)" id="like-'.$rw['id'].'"></i> 
    <span id="displaylike" style="color:#eaeaea">'.$rw['likes'].'</span>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down dislike" onmouseover="func('.$rw['id'].',event)" id="dislike-'.$rw['id'].'"></i>
 ';
echo $output;
```

**votes.js**

```
function func(x, e) {
$( "#like-"+x).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("clicked");
if($( "#like-"+x).prop('disabled')){alert();return;}
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight");
  if($( this ).hasClass( "highlight" )) {
    $("#dislike-"+x).prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $("#dislike-"+x).prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
$( "#dislike-"+x ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
if($( "#dislike-"+x ).prop('disabled')) {alert();return;}
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight");
  if($( this ).hasClass( "highlight" )) {
    $("#like-"+x).prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $("#like-"+x).prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
}
```

**vote.css**

```
i {
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You're giving multiple elements the same ID. ID's must be unique withing the document.

Comment: sorry I had almost forgotten that but can u suggest me a better option in this case please?

Comment: you can replace the id's with classes

Comment: use a class to target multiple items or give each element an unique id

Comment: ...give them different ID's? Set a prefix: `id="like-'.$rw['id'].'"`, `id="count-'.$rw['id'].'"` and `id="dislike-'.$rw['id'].'"` or similar?

Comment: you could use any data attributes to store the "id" that's supposed to link like and dislike button

Comment: … which then in turn would also mean that you can get rid of the ugly inline event handling.

Comment: The problem is solved! the onmouseover event was causing problems I added data attributes to store the id's as you guys said, and it's now working fine :D, Thanks